# Поиск всех вхождений шаблона в строку

Tags: python, re

У меня есть некоторая строка:

```
test = 'Тут Будет Нормальный Текст'
```

С помощью регулярки я ищу все последовательности, где будет три слова подряд с заглавной буквы.

```
pattern = r'[А-Я][а-я]+\s[А-Я][а-я]+\s[А-Я][а-я]+\b
```

После применения `re.findall(pattern, test)` я получу:

```
['Тут Будет Нормальный']
```

Как мне достать еще и 'Будет Нормальный Текст', чтобы итоговый результат выглядел как:

```
['Тут Будет Нормальный','Будет Нормальный Текст']
```

Comment: `([А-Я][а-я]+\s)(?=([А-Я][а-я]+\s[А-Я][а-я]+\b))` и берите group1+group2

Comment: @splash58 огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться Positive Lookahead

`([А-Я][а-я]+\s)(?=([А-Я][а-я]+\s[А-Я][а-я]+\b))`

и собирать полученные группы group1+group2

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/WoI9Ad/1)